# Calling constructor inside overloaded version

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

I have class shown below;

```
public class Film {
    public String   filmName;
    public String   filmImage;
    public String   imdbRating;
    public String   description;

    public Film(){
        super();
    }

    public void Film(String filmName,String filmImage,String imdbRating){
        this.filmName=filmName;
        this.filmImage=filmImage;
        this.imdbRating=imdbRating;
    }


    public Film(String filmName,String filmImage,String imdbRating,String description){
        this.description=description;
        //I want call the other one, because I don't want to repeat         
        this.Film(filmName,filmImage,imdbRating);

    }

}
```

Please take care on second definition of constructor **Film(String,String,String,String)**. Why I'm not able to call the **Film(String,String,String)** inside of second constructor?

Are there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You may call it as

```
this(filmName,filmImage,imdbRating)
```

But it should first statement in constructor

Answer (score 2):

1. `public void Film` is not a constructor definition, but a method. Remove `void`
2. You can call constructors with `this(...)` and this call should be the very first line in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Should be in this order, then you only implement the constructor in the more general version.

```
    public Film(){
        this(null,null,null,null);
    }

    public Film(String filmName,String filmImage,String imdbRating){
        this(filmName,filmImage,imdbRating,null);
    }


    public Film(String filmName,String filmImage,String imdbRating,String description){
        this.filmName=filmName;
        this.filmImage=filmImage;
        this.imdbRating=imdbRating; 
        this.description=description;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call other constructors with `this(a, b, c)` for Strings a, b, c. You're trying to call it with `this.Film` which is improper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

*this(filmName,filmImage,imdbRating)*

it should first statement in constructor